# anyone know how to fix this HTTP Status 404- not found error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE8aK.png)[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVklv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE0Uh.png)

thats the error message im receving, not ssure howw to fix it

tried these steps -

Check Project Structure: Double-check that your project structure is correct. Make sure the WEB-INF folder containing log.jsp is directly under your WebContent (or webapp) directory.

URL Pattern: Verify that the URL pattern in your @WebServlet annotation matches the URL you're trying to access. In your case, it's /LoggyMicroblog/.

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.jsp` is in your `WEB-INF` folder, and should not be. Nothing in there is directly addressable to the client. Put it directly inside of `webapp`.